# Is there a way to print a Java model in InteliJ prompt?

Tags: java, system.printing

When I sysout the **RestModel** in Java code, it's printed out like this.

```
[com.my.model.RestModel@14ab40d2]
```

Is there a way to display the Detail? (like Json?)

Comment: Implement toString. Consider lombok (will not be JSON though)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I print my Java object without getting "SomeType@2f92e0f4"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override your model's `toString()` method and have it print out the information you want in the format you want.